# preStart hook: a message to the actor itself

Tags: scala, akka

Let's say I override the `preStart` hook and send a message to `self`:

```
Class SomeActor extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    self ! SomeMessage
  }

  ...

}
```

Can I expect that `SomeMessage` will be the first message in the queue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, since actor creation happens asynchronously someone might have enqueued a message before the constructor or `preStart` actually run. If you need to ensure processing of this message before any other then you’ll need to use `become` and `stash`:

```scala
self ! SomeMessage

def receive = initial

def initial: Receive = {
  case SomeMessage =>
    // do stuff
    unstashAll()
    context become initialized
  case _ => stash()
}

def initialized: Receive = {
  // your normal behavior
}
```

You’ll need to mix in the `akka.actor.Stash` trait and configure this actor to use a `DequeBasedMailbox`.

Comment: How to do the same in java??