# Sending message on Actor startup with real (non-temp) sender ActorRef?

Tags: akka

I'd like an actor to send a message on startup and receive a reply later.

Sending the message from within `preStart` results in a temporary `sender` reference (because the Actor hasn't yet started?). So the reply will likely be a dead letter.

Any tips would be appreciated. Apologies if my premise is mis-informed - I am new to Akka.

Comment: You could send an initial message to your actor, that will trigger sending the start up message. Alternatively, make your actor stateful; its startup state would send the message and then it would transition to operational state, where it would expect to receive the response.

Comment: Thanks @BobDalgleish - does that entail a `become(receive)` call in `preStart`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to send a message to `self` in `preStart`:

```scala
class MyActor extends Actor {

  def preStart(): Unit = {
    self ! CallService
  }

  def receive = {
    case CallService =>
      (service ? ServiceRequest).mapTo[ServiceResponse].pipeTo(self)
    case ServiceResponse =>
      // do something with the response
  }
}
```

As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338502/865401), if you want the actor to send the message before it processes all other messages, then you could [`stash`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/actors.html#stash) the other messages:

```scala
class MyActor extends Actor with Stash {

  def preStart(): Unit = {
    self ! CallService
  }

  def uninitialized: Receive = {
    case CallService =>
      (service ? ServiceRequest).mapTo[ServiceResponse].pipeTo(self)
      unstashAll()
      context.become(initialized)
    case _ => stash() // if we get a message other than CallService, stash it
  }

  def initialized: Receive = {
    case ServiceResponse =>
      // do something with the response from the service
    case ...
  }

  def receive = uninitialized
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is indeed not correct: when preStart runs the actor is already fully started, it's `self` reference never is a temporary one. Without code it is impossible to help you further, though.

Answer (score 1):

The sender should always be considered "temporary" -- cf. this blog post, for example:

> The rule is simply never close over the sender method in a block of
>   code that is potentially executed in another thread, such as a
>   scheduled task or a Future. The trick is to capture the current sender
>   in a val, as illustrated below...

-- [Closing Over An Akka Actor Sender In The Receive](http://helenaedelson.com/?p=879)

Make a copy of sender, and then later when you are ready to reply, reply to that copy of the actorRef and not to "sender".